# Closing Hibernate Connection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using `Hibernate` for `DB` pooling. Connections are not closing properly. I am calling this:

```
HibernateManager.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().disconnect();
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Could you try calling close() on the current session.

Comment: Needs more details - which connection pool? how do you know connections are not closed? are you sure the connections should be closed rather than just returned to the pool and left open? what do the logs show?

Answer (score 2):

[`Session.disconnect()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#disconnect%28%29) does not do what you think it does:

> Disconnect the session from its underlying JDBC connection. This is intended for use in cases where the application has supplied the JDBC connection to the session and which require long-sessions (aka, conversations).

Typically you just want to either close() the Session or let the transaction management layer handle getting and closing connections.